# Using InStr to determine the amount of occurrences of a specific character?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing some data processing and I used the code

```
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "/") > 1 Then
    cell.Replace "/", ", "
End If
```

Now my understanding would be that if "/" appeared more than once it would then go ahead and replace it with ",". However, it seems as though even if there is only 1 "/" it still executes the replace. I'm no coding wizard but it seems like the math is a little flawed. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Edit: Full code

```
Sub Title()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, " ") > 0 Then
        cell.Value = " " & cell.Value & " "
    End If
Next cell
rng.Replace "  ", " "
'Data Breakdown

'Remove phrases
 rng.Replace "at *", ""
 rng.Replace "We're *", ""
 rng.Replace "We are *", ""
 rng.Replace "we're *", ""
 rng.Replace "we are *", ""

For Each cell In rng

  If (Len(myCell) - Len(Replace(myCell, "/", ""))) > 1 Then
    myCell = Replace(myCell.Text, "/", "")
  End If


If InStr(1, cell.Value, " Manager of ") > 0 Then
    cell.Replace " Manager of ", " Manager, "
End If

Next cell

rng.Replace " IT ", " IT, "
rng.Replace " Manager ", " Manager, "
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Instr finds the position in the string of the first occurrence, not a count of occurrences.  You are asking if the `/` is in position 2 or greater not if there are more than one `/`.  The replace will replace all occurrences.

Comment: Instr returns the location of the string being sought, not the count.

Comment: Have a look at the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811.aspx) of InStr function.

Comment: @ScottCraner What would you suggest as a solution to the issue?

Comment: `myCell` is not defined. `Option Explicit` would be your friend here.

Comment: How [Count specific characters in a cell](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-characters-in-a-cell) woks.

Comment: @dee I tried changing myCell to cell and to rng both already defined variables and it's still not working.

Comment: You have `For Each cell in rng`, and then `If If (Len(myCell) ...`.  In this context, `myCell` is not assigned any value. You should do `For Each myCell in rng...` (and clean up your earlier use of `cell` as well, up to and including the declaration).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace all of the "/" if there are more than two, then:

```
If (Len(myCell) - Len(Replace(myCell, "/", ""))) > 1 Then
    myCell = Replace(myCell.Text, "/", "")
End If
```

If you want something else, please be specific.

Comment: @ScottCraner Oops.  Thanks

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear. This is exactly what I would like to accomplish however something in the answer provided does not work for me. For some reason when I look step by step, it gets to your if statement then goes to end if as if it didn't meet the standards listed

Comment: @MedicatedGorilla Edit your question to show the actual code you are using.  I don't like to use `cell` as a variable since it is also a key word in VBA.  So you may have messed something up there.

Comment: @MedicatedGorilla you've used `myCell` but you're also using `cell` still as the loop variable. In this case, `myCell` is never assigned a value and defaults to empty/nullstring. Replace **all** instances of `cell` with `myCell`. Using `Option Explicit` to require variable declaration would help alert you to typos like this :)

Comment: @DavidZemens THANK YOU! I'm not that great at VBA yet so thanks for telling me that!

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld !

Answer (score 0):

The [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx) operator makes it easier to check if a value contains or starts/ends with something:

```
For Each cell In rng

    If cell Like "*/*/*" Then cell.Replace "/", ", "    ' * matches 0 or more characters

Next cell
```

Another option can be to split the value and check upper bound of the result array:

```
For Each cell In rng

    a = Split(cell, "/")

    If UBound(a) > 1 Then cell.Value = Join(a, ", ")

Next cell
```

You can also replace all cells at once without loop with Excel Data Filter:

```
Set rng = Columns("F")          ' the filter needs the first header cell

rng.AutoFilter 1, "*/*/*"       ' add Excel Data Filter to the Range
rng.Replace "/", ", ", xlPart   ' ignores the filtered cells
rng.AutoFilter                  ' optional to remove the filter
```